# Forked Service getting restarted as soon as it starts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, systemd

I am having the below systemd script as below

```
[Unit]
Description= TaskParticipant Service

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/bash bin/start-participant.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash bin/stop-participant.sh
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/opt/taskparticipant
User=javauser
Group=javauser
PrivateTmp=true
TimeoutSec=90
SuccessExitStatus=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After doing the `systemctl start tp`

I am getting the below error

```
[centos@mmanthena bin]$ sudo systemctl status tp.service 
● tp.service - TaskParticipant
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-08-06 07:20:19 GMT; 2s ago
  Process: 6635 ExecStop=/bin/bash bin/stop-participant.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6504 ExecStart=/bin/bash bin/start-participant.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6577 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 06 07:20:17 manthena systemd[1]: Starting TaskParticipant...
Aug 06 07:20:17 manthena bash[6504]: **************************************
Aug 06 07:20:17 manthena bash[6504]: Starting TaskParticipant
Aug 06 07:20:17 manthena bash[6504]: **************************************
Aug 06 07:20:18 manthena systemd[1]: Started - TaskParticipant.
Aug 06 07:20:19 manthena bash[6635]: Stopping Participant
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# JVM ARGUMENTS
jvm_min_heap_size="128m"
jvm_min_heap="-Xms${jvm_min_heap_size}"
jvm_max_heap_size="256m"
jvm_max_heap="-Xmx${jvm_max_heap_size}"


# GC Configuration
jvm_gc_options="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/acds/var"
jvm_gc_log_option="-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:${logs_dir}/task-participant-gc.log"

jvm_arg_line="${jvm_min_heap} ${jvm_max_heap} ${jvm_gc_options} ${jvm_gc_log_option} -Dlog4j.configuration=task_participant_log4j.conf"

config_file_option="-cf ${conf_dir}/acds_taskmanager.conf"
host_name_option="-H ${HOSTNAME}"

java_arg_line="${config_file_option} ${host_name_option}"

# Run java
main_class=io.manoj.acds.taskparticipant.TaskParticipant
cmdline="java -cp ${cp} ${jvm_arg_line} ${main_class} ${java_arg_line} $*"

cd $root_dir

nohup $cmdline &
tp_pid=$(jps -l | grep io.manoj.acds.taskparticipant.TaskParticipant | awk '{print $1}')
echo ${tp_pid} > ${tp_pid_file}
```

My Expectation was that the process should start and run in the background as the parent is the bin/start-participant.sh and it starts a java process but I see that the process is getting restarted on starting with the systemctl

On starting manually it's working as expected (i.e Running the Script directly works fine)

Comment: Might worth a try  remove the `Restart=on-failure` part in the unit file for troubleshooting, and see if the service still restarting again and again.

Comment: Could you please try to remove `RemainAfterExit=no` once and let me know then?

Comment: @Edvin I have tried removing it , but had the same issue.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 tried it as you said , but found the same issue.

Comment: where `$root_dir` is came from. It is not defined in the script just used to `cd $root_dir`

Comment: Might you consider *not* implementing it as a forking service, and switching to `simple`? The situation where `Type=forking` is valuable is when a program does its initial setup before forking, and is able to handle requests successfully immediately afterwards, so the time of the fork lets systemd know when to consider the process to have finished starting up. That's not the case here, so forking adds extra complexity and bugs, but no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: On a different side note, your code has some bugs that will become apparent if you ever try to pass a command-line argument that requires quotes or spaces. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) on why strings should not be used to store argument lists, and describing the more robust alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Work directory I believe.

If you defined variables in `bash_profiles` or `bashrc` that not get used by the systemd unit. 
You could use `EnvironmentFile=` section for that.

Most likely the `$root_dir` variable is empty so `cd $root_dir` change the working director from what systemd unit defined ( `WorkingDirectory=/opt/taskparticipant` ) to javauser home directory. I think this is not the intended behavior.

This can be verified if you change line `cd $root_dir` to `cd ${root_dir:?}` this way script exit with error if `$root_dir` variable is empty.

Comment: I have given sourced the setup.inc in the script above but here it's missing tough. but I am getting the same issue.